# Is there a kable() function for adding a header below a table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I want to add a header below my table with `kableExtra`, is this possible or is there an easy work around? I want to add two header (rows below table) last one spanning from column 2-13 with "Confidence Level C" and second last row with confidence levels 50%, 60%, 70% ... 99.99% Thanks

```
options(digits = 4)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(latex2exp)
library(tidyverse)

# critical t-values
t.table = tibble(r.tail.25 = qt(.75, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)),
             r.tail.20 = qt(.80, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)),
             r.tail.15 = qt(.85, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)), 
             r.tail.10 = qt(.90, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)),
             r.tail.05 = qt(.95, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)),
             r.tail.025 = qt(.975, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)),
             r.tail.02 = qt(.98, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)),
             r.tail.01 = qt(.99, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)),
             r.tail.005 = qt(.995, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)),
             r.tail.0025 = qt(.9975, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)),
             r.tail.001 = qt(.999, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)),
             r.tail.0005 = qt(.999, df= c(1:30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 100, 1000)))

z_values = qnorm(c(.75, .80, .85, .90, .95, .975,
               .98, .99, .995, .9975, .999, .9995), 0, 1)
z_values_row <- as.data.frame(t(z_values))
colnames(z_values_row) = colnames(t.table)
t.table = t.table %>% 
bind_rows(z_values_row)
t.table = t.table %>% 
mutate(df = c(1:30,40,50,60, 80, 100, 1000, "$z^{*}$")) %>% 
select(df, everything())
# Create students t table
kable(t.table,
  booktabs = TRUE,
  col.names =  c("**_df_**", ".25", ".20",".15",".10", ".05", ".025", ".02", 
                 ".01", "0.005", ".0025", ".001", ".0005"), 
  escape = FALSE,
  caption = "t verdeling kritieke t-waarden",
  linesep = "",
  align = c('r'),
  digits=3) %>% 
  kable_styling(font_size = 10) %>% 
  column_spec(1, bold = T, border_right = T) %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Upper tail probability $p$" = 12))
```

Comment: Can you produce the kind of table you want to reproduce.

Comment: No kable() function. But solutions exist. Knit to pdf or html?

Comment: html for now! thanks

Comment: @BenjaminTelkamp Hm, interesting. But I haven't skills and knowledge to do that. Maybe someone could help. The easiest solution - add info into footnotes...

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts, i guess i'll make an new table and paste it just below with kable guess that will work. Anyway you deserve my book, when it;s translated into English!

Comment: @BenjaminTelkamp You can do it. But you should look after for this "frankenstein" table. We can recieve an extra white space or vise versa - an overlay when printing... You are a writer. Cool :)

Comment: @manro, I googled "frankenstein" table, only got real tables... very funny, me not understand!

Comment: @BenjaminTelkamp This is the a "figure of speech". Frankenstein was made from the pieces. Like a combined table :)